# Keyword Search first then display rest of record set randomly

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting

What might be the best way to search a record set using keyword $search and display those first and then pull the remaining records into the query and have them ordered randomly. In other words place search results at the top and then remaining records randomly. Here is the first part of my search:

```
SELECT first_name, last_name, title, agency, address, 
       phone, more_info, description, img_name, active 
  FROM realtor 
  WHERE MATCH as rank (first_name, last_name, agency, description) 
        AGAINST ('$search' IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
  ORDER BY rank DESC
```

and then I would like to UNION this with the remaining record set using ORDER BY RAND()
Or is there a better way to perform this query? This is my first attempt at UNION.

Also my rank does not seem to work as if I search on fname lname I don't get fname lname record first as many of the records have lname in title column. Is there a better way to do this? THANKS

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
SELECT first_name, last_name, title, agency, address, 
       phone, more_info, description, img_name, active, 
        MATCH     (first_name, last_name, agency, description)   AGAINST ('$search' IN BOOLEAN MODE) as relv
  FROM realtor 
      HAVING relv>0  order by relv DESC
```

Comment: I got the first part to work by removing IN BOOLEAN MODE and am now working on adding rest of the set of records using UNION ALL. Here is what I have so far $result = mysql_query("SELECT first_name, last_name, title, agency, address, phone, more_info, description, img_name, active FROM realtor WHERE MATCH (first_name, last_name, agency, description) AGAINST ('$search') UNION ALL SELECT first_name, last_name, title, agency, address, phone, more_info, description, img_name, active FROM realtor WHERE NOT MATCH (first_name, last_name, agency, description) AGAINST ('$search') ORDER BY RAND()");

Comment: Please notice that your method may increase server load (specially with large table). Can you test my offered code without **HAVING relv>0 ** . Then you would get all matched rows and after them, you would have unrelated rows.`SELECT first_name, last_name, title, agency, address, 
       phone, more_info, description, img_name, active, 
        MATCH     (first_name, last_name, agency, description)   AGAINST ('$search' IN BOOLEAN MODE) as relv
  FROM realtor 
       order by relv DESC
`